# How to plot different dataframe data in one figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need some guidance to plot:

1. scatter plot of df1 data: time vs y use the hue for the column z
2. line plot df2 data: time vs. y
3. a single line at y=c (c is a constant)

y data in df1 and df2 are different but they are in the same range.

I do not know where to begin. Any guidance is appreciated.

More explanation. A portion of data is presented here. I want to plot:

1. scatter plot of time vs CO2
2. finding the yearly rolling average of CO2 (from 01/01/2016 to 09/30/2019 based on hourly data. So the first average will be from "01/01/2016 00" to "12/31/2016 23" and second average will be from "01/01/2016 01" to "01/01/2017 00") (like the trend in plot below)
3. finding the maximum of all the data and through a line over the plot (like straight line below)

[image]

### Sample data

```py
data = {'Date':['0     01/14/2016 00', '01/14/2016 01','01/14/2016 02','01/14/2016 03','01/14/2016 04','01/14/2016 05','01/14/2016 06','01/14/2016 07','01/14/2016 08','01/14/2016 09','01/14/2016 10','01/14/2016 11','01/14/2016 12','01/14/2016 13','01/14/2016 14','01/14/2016 15','01/14/2016 16','01/14/2016 17','01/14/2016 18','01/14/2016 19'],
        'CO2':[2415.9,2416.5,2429.8,2421.5,2422.2,2428.3,2389.1,2343.2,2444.,2424.8,2429.6,2414.7,2434.9,2420.6,2420.5,2397.1,2415.6,2417.4,2373.2,2367.9],
        'Year':[2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# DataFrame view
                Date     CO2  Year
 0     01/14/2016 00  2415.9  2016
       01/14/2016 01  2416.5  2016
       01/14/2016 02  2429.8  2016
       01/14/2016 03  2421.5  2016
       01/14/2016 04  2422.2  2016
```

Comment: Some research on matplolib doc will open the path : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/legend_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-legend-demo-py

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Comment: pass an axis object to the plot command, e.g. `df.plot(ax=ax); df2.plot.scatter(ax=ax)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### using `matplotlib.pyplot`:

- `plt.hlines` to add a horizontal line at a constant

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# with synthetic data
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'CO2': [np.random.randint(2000, 2500) for _ in range(783)],
        'Date': pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2016', end='1/1/2019').tolist()}

# create the dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# verify Date is in datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# set Date as index so .rolling can be used
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# add rolling mean
df['rolling'] = df['CO2'].rolling('365D').mean()

# plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(x=df.index, y='CO2', data=df, label='data')
plt.plot(df.index, 'rolling', data=df, color='black', label='365 day rolling mean')
plt.hlines(max(df['CO2']), xmin=min(df.index), xmax=max(df.index), color='red', linestyles='dashed', label='Max')
plt.hlines(np.mean(df['CO2']), xmin=min(df.index), xmax=max(df.index), color='green', linestyles='dashed', label='Mean')
plt.xticks(rotation='45')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

### Plot using synthetic data:

[image]

### Issues with the Date format in the data from the op:

- Use a regular expression to fix the `Date` column
- Place the code to fix `Date`, just before `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

```py
import re

# your data
                Date     CO2  Year
 0     01/14/2016 00  2415.9  2016
       01/14/2016 01  2416.5  2016
       01/14/2016 02  2429.8  2016
       01/14/2016 03  2421.5  2016
       01/14/2016 04  2422.2  2016

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', x)[0]))

# fixed Date column
       Date     CO2  Year
 01/14/2016  2415.9  2016
 01/14/2016  2416.5  2016
 01/14/2016  2429.8  2016
 01/14/2016  2421.5  2016
 01/14/2016  2422.2  2016
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Does .rolling('365D').mean() works for my my data as well? 0     01/14/2016 00, 01/14/2016 01,01/14/2016 02  ------------------- as you can see, some data are missing, in one day I may have 24 data and another one I may have 10 data, we may even have some missing days. How does it move over the data?

Comment: @PouyanEbrahimi No, you have to fix your date to be an actual datetime format.  What are you importing the data from (csv, txt)?  Please paste the top 5 rows of data into your question, as they appear in the file.  It doesn't seem like the data is being imported correctly, based on the `Date` data.

Comment: @PouyanEbrahimi I've add a line of code at the bottom to fix your `Date` column

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **dual-axis chart**. It will ideally look the same as yours because both the axes will be the same scale. Can directly plot using pandas data frames

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# create a color map for the z column
color_map = {'z_val1':'red', 'z_val2':'blue', 'z_val3':'green', 'z_val4':'yellow'}

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx() #second axis within the first

# define scatter plot
df1.plot.scatter(x = 'date',
                 y = 'CO2',
                 ax = ax1,
                 c = df['z'].apply(lambda x:color_map[x]))

# define line plot
df2.plot.line(x = 'date',
         y = 'MA_CO2', #moving average in dataframe 2
         ax = ax2)


# plot the horizontal line at y = c (constant value)
ax1.axhline(y = c, color='r', linestyle='-')

# to fit the chart properly
plt.tight_layout()
```